# Can't load image with Picasso (Android)

Tags: android, image, url, picasso

I'm trying to display an image in an ImageView with the Picasso Library but I don't know why the image doesn't load. Can you help me please ?

In the build.gradle (dependencies) :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

In the MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.imageview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
    }
}
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml :
(I don't know if it's really necessary)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In the activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="154dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="#A0A" />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I would like just display the image with the url like in the Picasso's documentation. Did i forget something ? Or change something in settings ?

Thank you !

Comment: show your `activity_main`

Comment: The code that you have posted works as expected. Please add your activity_main.xml to the post. Also check if your device (or emulator) has internet connection.

Comment: Sorry i forget the xml I edited it.

Comment: Yes the device has internet connection I can search in Google Chrome

Comment: Try to add .placeHolder(...), .error(...) to Picasso call for reserach the problem

Comment: I did it with ".error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)." and i have an error but i don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url is not working,

Try this;

Picasso.get().load("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg").into(imageView);

instead of

Picasso.get().load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg").into(imageView);

Answer (score 0):

Replace below. Pass the Activity reference into picasso.

```
      Picasso.with(MainActivity.this) 
 .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: The method with() is not avalaible with this implementation but thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

> android:src="#A0A"

from your activity_main.xml. You don't need to put any source in the xml, you can do that with

```
.load.....
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder) // Image to show before loading url of image
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error) // Image to show is error occurred while loading url
```